# How find the value of the $P$?

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

For a prime $p$,let
$$S_{1}=\{(a,b,c)\in Z^3,P|(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+1)\}$$
and
$$S_{2}=\{(a,b,c)\in Z^3,P|(a^2b^2c^2(a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2c^2)\}$$

Find all $p$ for which
$$S_{1}\subset S_{2}$$

my try,I found when $a=b=c=1,$,then
so

> $$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+1=4$$
>   $$a^2b^2c^2(a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2c^2)=4$$
>   so let  $P=2$ is such condtion,
>
> and  let $$a=b=1,c=2$$,then
>   $$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+1=10$$
>   $$a^2b^2c^2(a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2c^2)=20$$
>   so let  $P=2 or 5$ is such condtion,
>   Have other prime of number$P$?

Comment: Note that you're asking for what prime numbers $P$ is it true that $$\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}: P \mid a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + a^2c^2 + 1 \implies P \mid a^2b^2c^2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + a^2b^2c^2).$$ So at least your _reasoning_ that $P = 2$ and $P = 5$ satisfy is incorrect: you should show the implication for all $a, b, c$.

Comment: Where did the question come from - I'm intrigued

Comment: A computer search reveals that $2,3,5,13$
and $17$ are solutions, and that no other prime $ \leq 2000$ is a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, we rephrase the question: We are looking for all primes $p$ s.t. $$p \mid (a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+1), a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow p \mid a^2b^2c^2(a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2c^2)$$

We first show that no prime $p>17$ has this property. It will then be a trivial matter to check the remaining primes (or refer to the comment by Ewan Delanoy regarding a computer search)

**Lemma 1:** We can find $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ such that $$a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, (\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=1$$ if and only if $p$ does not have the required property.

**Proof:** Suppose that such $a, b$ exist. We can then put $c^2 \equiv -\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2} \pmod{p}$ (since $ a^2b^2+1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ we have $c \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$), and we get $$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+1 \equiv a^2b^2+1+(a^2+b^2)c^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

now $a, b, c \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ so $p \nmid a^2b^2c^2$. Also since $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$ we have $(a^2 \pm 1)(b^2 \pm 1) \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ so $c^2 \equiv -\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2} \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$. Thus

\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2c^2 & \equiv c^2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+1)+(a^2+b^2)(1-c^4) \\
& \equiv (a^2+b^2)(1-c^4) \\
& \not \equiv 0\pmod{p}
\end{align}

Therefore $p$ does not have the required property.

Now suppose that $p$ does not have the required property. Then there exists $a, b, c$ such that $p \mid (a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+1)$ and $p \nmid a^2b^2c^2(a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2c^2)$. We must then have $a, b \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ so $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$. If $a^2 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$ then

\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2c^2 & \equiv a^2+a^4b^2+a^4c^2+a^2b^2c^2 \\
& \equiv a^2(1+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2) \\
& \equiv 0 \pmod{p}
\end{align}

, a contradiction, so $a^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$. Similarly $b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$.

Note that $a^2b^2+1 \equiv c^2(a^2+b^2) \pmod{p}$ and $c \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ so $a^2b^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. If either is $0 \pmod{p}$, then both are, so $a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2c^2 \equiv (a^2+b^2)+(a^2b^2+1)c^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, a contradiction. Thus $a^2+b^2 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

Finally we have $c^2 \equiv (a^2b^2+1)(a^2+b^2)$ so clearly $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=1$. We have thus proved Lemma 1.

**We proceed.** Consider $p>17$. Assume on the contrary that $p$ has the required properties.

**Case 1:** $(\frac{-1}{p})=1$.

If $(\frac{3}{p})=1$, take $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 16 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 49 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{49}{16}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{3}{p})=-1$.

If $(\frac{7}{p})=1$, take $a^2 \equiv 7 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 9 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 16 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 64 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{64}{16}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{7}{p})=-1$.

If $(\frac{5}{p})=1$, take $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 9 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 21 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{7}{3}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{5}{p})=-1$.

If $(\frac{2}{p})=-1$, then $(\frac{6}{p})=1$ so take $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 6 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 10 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 25 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{5}{2}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{2}{p})=1$.

If $(\frac{17}{p})=1$, take $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 8 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 17 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{17}{8}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{17}{p})=-1$. Now take $a^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 8 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 10 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 17 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{17}{10}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property.

**Case 2:** $(\frac{-1}{p})=-1$. Then $p \not =37$.

*Case 2a:* $(\frac{2}{p})=-1$.

*Case 2a i):* $(\frac{3}{p})=1$.

If $(\frac{5}{p})=-1$, take $a^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 6 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 10 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{5}{3}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{5}{p})=1$. Take $a^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 8 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 16 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{16}{8}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

*Case 2a ii):*  $(\frac{3}{p})=-1$.

If $(\frac{37}{p})=1$, take $a^2 \equiv 6 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 6 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17, p \not =37$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 12 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 37 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{37}{12}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{37}{p})=-1$.

If $(\frac{13}{p})=-1$, take $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 16 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 20 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 65 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{13}{4}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{13}{p})=1$. Take $a^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 9 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 13 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 37 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{37}{13}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

*Case 2b:* $(\frac{2}{p})=1$.

If $(\frac{3}{p})=-1$, take $a^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{p}$. Note that since $p>17$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \equiv 6 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv 9 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Finally $(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{3}{2}}{p})=1$ so $p$ does not have the required property, a contradiction.

Thus $(\frac{3}{p})=1$.

We proceed by strong induction on $n$ to show that $(\frac{n}{p})=1 \, \forall n \in \{1, 2, \ldots, \frac{p-1}{2} \}$.

When $n=1, 2, 3, 4$, the statement is clearly true.

Suppose that the statement holds for $4 \leq n=k<\frac{p-1}{2}$.

If $k+1$ is composite, write $k+1=cd$ where $1<c,d \leq k$. Then by the induction hypothesis $(\frac{c}{p})=(\frac{d}{p})=1$, so $(\frac{k}{p})=(\frac{c}{p})(\frac{d}{p})=1$.

If $k+1$ is prime, then $k$ is composite, so write $k=st$ where $1<s,t \leq k$, and take $a^2 \equiv s \pmod{p}, b^2 \equiv t \pmod{p}$. Note that since $1<s, t, s+t<p-1$, $a^2, b^2 \not \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}, a^2+b^2 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, a^2b^2+1 \equiv k+1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Also $s+t \leq st=k$ so by the induction hypothesis $(\frac{s+t}{p})=1$. Finally since $p$ satisfies the required property, $-1=(\frac{-\frac{a^2b^2+1}{a^2+b^2}}{p})=(\frac{-\frac{k+1}{s+t}}{p})=-(\frac{k+1}{p})$, so $(\frac{k+1}{p})=1$

We are thus done by induction.

Therefore $(\frac{n}{p})=1 \, \forall n \in \{1, 2, \ldots, \frac{p-1}{2} \}$. Thus $(\frac{-1}{p})=(\frac{p-1}{p})=(\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{p})(\frac{2}{p})=1(1)=1$, a contradiction.

**As such, we have shown that if $p>17$, then $p$ does not satisfy the required property. It remains to check $p \leq 17$, and this is a relatively trivial matter, which can be easily done by a computer check, or if one so wishes, listing the cases with the help of Lemma 1.**